# Class members get lost when function/class got imported

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am losing my class members when I call a function from an imported file to add a class member (class definition in the same file). When the function and class definition is in the main.py file it obviously works.
Here the example code:

**test.py**

```
from functions import*

load_list_into_class("one")
print("test")
```

**functions.py**

```
class testclass:
    pass

def load_list_into_class(listname):
    globals()[listname] = testclass()
```

What can I do to keep my class members after I called the `load_list_into_class` function?

Might be a stupid question, I just started to learn Python :)

Comment: Is your indentation correct?

Comment: what makes you think it doesnt work ? globals() should contain "one" after calling this ... even in a different imported file

Comment: idention should be allright.
It's not working, I cannot access "one" as a class object. Error msg: NameError: Name "one" is not defined

Comment: Why do you think this doesn't work? What do you mean by "class members" here? Your function, `load_list_into_class`, which basically just does `globals()[listname] = testclass()` is a terrible practice. Why are you dynamically modifying globals like that?

Comment: Anyway, you are modifying the global namespace of the `function` module. Not of the module where you import

Comment: Because I want to create class instances which have the name (and therefore can be accessible) of a defined list

Comment: @soderdaen don't do that. That is a bad practice. Don't dynamically create variables. Use another container, perhaps a `dict`, if you need to access an object using a string object.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for the advice. How would I create those class instances then?